# I want to define (create) and use different variable (using suffix) through loop (specially for loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-length, nested-for-loop, suffix-array

I want to create multiple variable through for loop to further use and compare in the program.

**Here is the code -**

```
for i in range(0,len(Header_list)):
  (f'len_{i} = {len(Header_list[i]) + 2 }')
  print(len_0);print(f'len{i}')    
  for company in Donar_list:
     print(company[i],f"len_{i}")
     if len(str(company[i])) > len((f"len_{i}")) :
        (f'len_{i}') = len(str(company[i]))
        print(f"len_{i}")
```

But what is happening, though I managed to create variable **len_0,len_1,len_2**... in line-2, in line - 3 I also can print len_0..etc variable by only using print(len_0), but I can't print it the values of these by - print(f'len_{i}')

In line 5 I also can't compare with the cofition with my intension. I want it do create variable and compare it further when as it necessary, in this case under for loop.What should I do now? I am a beginner and I can do it using if statement but that wouldn't be efficient, also my intention is not to create any **data structure ** for this.

I don't know whether I could manage to deliver you what I am trying to say. Whatever I just wanna create different variable using suffix and also comprare them through for loop in THIS scenario.

Comment: Unless it's critical to dynamically create variables, using a dictionary is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you share the data in `Header_list`?

Comment: company_details = "Company ID, Company Name, Name Code, Total Donations Paid, Donation Status"

Header_list = company_details.split(", ")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dynamically creating variables, I would HIGHLY recommend checking out dictionaries.
Dictionaries allow you to store variables with an associated key, as so:

```py
variable_dict = dict()
for i in range(0,len(Header_list)):
  variable_dict[f'len_{i}'] = {len(Header_list[i]) + 2 }
  print(len_0)
  print(f'len{i}')
  for company in Donar_list:
     print(company[i],f"len_{i}")
     if len(str(company[i])) > len(variable_dict[f"len_{i}"]) :
        variable_dict[f'len_{i}'] = len(str(company[i]))
        print(f"len_{i}")
```

This allows you to access the values using the same key:

```py
len_of_4 = variable_dict['len_4']
```

If you REALLY REALLY need to dynamically create variables, you could use the `exec` function to run strings as python code. It's important to note that the `exec` function is not safe in python, and could be used to run any potentially malicious code:

```py
for i in range(0,len(Header_list)):
  exec(f'len_{i} = {len(Header_list[i]) + 2 }')
  print(len_0);print(f'len{i}')    
  for company in Donar_list:
     print(company[i],f"len_{i}")
     if exec(f"len(str(company[i])) > len(len_{i})"):
        exec(f'len_{i} = len(str(company[i]))')
        print(f"len_{i}")
```

Comment: if I use exec then in if statement it gives me Nonr value and error said cant't concentrat > between int and none type

Comment: I changed a line to fix it, but I still recommend you don't use the exec solution.

Answer (score 0):

In python everything is object so use current module as object and use it like this

```
import sys
module = sys.modules[__name__]
Header_list=[0,1,2,3,4]
len_ = len(Header_list)
for i in range(len_):
  setattr(module, f"len_{i}", Header_list[i]+2)

print(len_0)
print(len_1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Header_list=[0,1,2,3,4]
for i in range(0,5):
  exec(f'len_{i} = {Header_list[i] + 2 }')
  print(f'len{i}')
```

output:

```
len0
len1
len2
len3
len4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: `exec` should almost always be avoided.  In this case it looks like OP just needs a `dict`.